# checkbox validation like I Agree to the Terms and Condition jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox

```js
function toggleDisabled(target) {
  var confirm = $("input:checkbox:checked");
  if (!confirm.length > 0) {
    $("#confirm").addClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $("#confirm").removeClass('disabled');
  }
}

var $notnull = $('.notnull');

$(document).on('keyup change', '.notnull', function(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget)
  toggleDisabled(e.currentTarget);

});

$notnull.each(function(i, el) {
  toggleDisabled(el);
});

function reload() {
  $notnull.each(function(i, el) {
    toggleDisabled(el);
  });
}

function toggleDisabledNavButton(target) {
  var $target = $(target);

  var basic = $target.find('input').hasClass('disabled');
  if (basic) {
    $("#add").addClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $("#add").removeClass('disabled');
  }

}
var detailscontainer = $('.notnull');

$(document).on('keyup change click', 'input.notnull', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  toggleDisabledNavButton($(e.currentTarget).closest('.info'));



});

detailscontainer.each(function(i, el) {
  toggleDisabledNavButton(el.closest('.info'));
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  border-color: red;
  background: gray;
  //pointer-events: none;

}
input[type=checkbox].disabled {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='info'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" class="notnull disabled" id="confirm">
  <label for="confirm">Confirm</label>
  <input type="button" name="" value="Add" class="notnull disabled" id="add">
</div>
```

I want to create a Validation like **I Agree to the Terms and Condition** I made several function to run the script. When I added the code to check if the the checkbox has no class `disabled` the checkbox does not get checked anymore. I want to make this code work because i want to add more checkbox in the validation like Legal age etc. I cant find what i did wrong and i cant pinpoint why the checkbox does not get checked anymore.

Question:

1. Why is my checkbox does not get checked.

This is the code before added the `function toggleDisabledNavButton(target)`

```js
function toggleDisabled(target) {
  var confirm = $("input:checkbox:checked");
  if (!confirm.length > 0) {
    $("#confirm").addClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $("#confirm").removeClass('disabled');
  }
}

var $notnull = $('.notnull');

$(document).on('keyup change', '.notnull', function(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget)
  toggleDisabled(e.currentTarget);

});

$notnull.each(function(i, el) {
  toggleDisabled(el);
});

function reload() {
  $notnull.each(function(i, el) {
    toggleDisabled(el);
  });
}
```

```css
.disabled {
  border-color: red;
  background: gray;
  //pointer-events: none;

}
input[type=checkbox].disabled {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='info'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" class="notnull disabled" id="confirm">
  <label for="confirm">Confirm</label>
  <input type="button" name="" value="Add" class="notnull disabled" id="add">
</div>
```

Expected :

1. when the checkbox is checked it should remove the red border on the checkbox and the button as well. I dont see the happening. Right now i cant even check the checkbox.

Comment: so what is the behaviour you want?

Comment: on load they both have disabled class when i `click on the checkbox and it is checked` remove the disabled on the checkbox. then on button click check if checkbox has class disabled or not if not submit. it works fine without the `function toggleDisabledNavButton(target)` after i added it the checkbox cannot be checked anymore @lordkain

Comment: @lordkain updated the question so you can see the difference

Comment: you dont do anything with the button! you only change the class of the checkbox. Give you button an id and then add soem script thata removes the disabled property

Comment: added an answer, please mark the best answer as valid on, this may help future users with the same problem!  @Martin1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a working one. I just copied it and pasted,, didnt edit anything..

```js
function toggleDisabled(target) {
  var confirm = $("input:checkbox:checked");
  if (!confirm.length > 0) {
    $("#confirm").addClass('disabled');
    $("#add").addClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $("#confirm").removeClass('disabled');
    $("#add").removeClass('disabled');
  }
}

var $notnull = $('.notnull');

$(document).on('keyup change', '.notnull', function(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget)
  toggleDisabled(e.currentTarget);

});

$notnull.each(function(i, el) {
  toggleDisabled(el);
});

function reload() {
  $notnull.each(function(i, el) {
    toggleDisabled(el);
  });
}
```

```css
.disabled {
  border-color: red;
  background: gray;
  //pointer-events: none;

}
input[type=checkbox].disabled {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='info'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" class="notnull disabled" id="confirm">
  <label for="confirm">Confirm</label>
  <input type="button" name="" value="Add" class="notnull disabled" id="add">
</div>
```

Remove the notnull class from your checkbox, then tick mark will appear

```js
function toggleDisabled(target) {
  var confirm = $("input:checkbox:checked");
  if (!confirm.length > 0) {
    $("#confirm").addClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $("#confirm").removeClass('disabled');
  }
}

var $notnull = $('.notnull');

$(document).on('keyup change', '.notnull', function(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget)
  toggleDisabled(e.currentTarget);

});

$notnull.each(function(i, el) {
  toggleDisabled(el);
});

function reload() {
  $notnull.each(function(i, el) {
    toggleDisabled(el);
  });
}

function toggleDisabledNavButton(target) {
  var $target = $(target);

  var basic = $target.find('input').hasClass('disabled');
  if (basic) {
    $("#add").addClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $("#add").removeClass('disabled');
  }

}
var detailscontainer = $('.notnull');

$(document).on('keyup change click', 'input.notnull', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  toggleDisabledNavButton($(e.currentTarget).closest('.info'));



});

detailscontainer.each(function(i, el) {
  toggleDisabledNavButton(el.closest('.info'));
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  border-color: red;
  background: gray;
  //pointer-events: none;

}
input[type=checkbox].disabled {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='info'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" class="disabled" id="confirm">
  <label for="confirm">Confirm</label>
  <input type="button" name="" value="Add" class="notnull disabled" id="add">
</div>
```

Comment: how can you explain because the `toggleDisabled(target)` should take of that. when i dont have this `function toggleDisabledNavButton(target)` it works perfectly when i added it started to behave like this not getting checked

Comment: when the checkbox is checked it should remove the red border on the checkbox and the button. I dont see the happening

Comment: its because u didnt specify anything to remove the red mark on the submit button,, i have edited it,, now its working

Answer (score 0):

You may have mistakenly used the term "**notnull**" in the class name in following portion of your code:

```
<div class='info'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" class="notnull disabled" id="confirm">
  <label for="confirm">Confirm</label>
  <input type="button" name="" value="Add" class="notnull disabled" id="add">
</div>
```

if you erase it , I hope your checkbox will work.

Comment: not because by default i added the class so that on load it is disabled. it will remove the disabled class only if the checkbox is checked as you can see in the second sample

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the code so we are back to basics.

javascript:

```
$('#confirm').on('click', function() {


   if ($('#confirm').length > 0 ) {
        $('#confirm').removeClass('disabled'); // remove red border
       $('#confirm').attr('disabled', 'true'); // disable button
       $('#buttonSend').removeClass('disabled'); // remove class diabled so user can click button
  } 
  });
```

And youre html i added an id tot the button

```
id="buttonSend"
```

for example see 
https://jsfiddle.net/9Lky7ktw/

Comment: i want my code to work this one is different from my code... I am asking why i cant check my checkbox not to create new code